# Display same file successive pages on Emacs split screen

Tags: emacs

I've done this before, years ago, so I know the answer is out there. However the google-space is heavily polluted with namespace collisions, especially new user guides.

This is what I'd like to do in Emacs 21:

Split the screen on a given file buffer (C-x 3).
As I page through the first screen (C-v), the next page of the file is automatically displayed on the second.

To be clear, the next line in the file after the last line on the left screen should be the first line on the right screen, always.

Any help?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you trying to do that instead of just keeping a single window?

Comment: So I can see twice as much of the same file at once, without having to C-x o and page the other window of the same buffer.

Comment: My bad---I'd read that as a `C-x 2` and missed the visual idea.

Comment: `scroll-all-mode` is great for keeping movement in independent buffers in sync, but for your description it's most definitely `follow-mode` that you want. You should really re-allocate the accepted answer to aartist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `scroll-all-mode`

```
scroll-all-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `scroll-all.el'.
(scroll-all-mode &optional arg)

Toggle Scroll-All minor mode.
With arg, turn Scroll-All minor mode on if arg is positive, off otherwise.
When Scroll-All mode is on, scrolling commands entered in one window
apply to all visible windows in the same frame.
```

Set up the windows appropriately, and then turn on `scroll-all-mode`, and from then on all windows scroll together

Comment: Thanks! This works until I do a M-< at which point it breaks the assocation, or I page down to the bottom of the buffer and then page down once more. *SL* is still indicated but they no longer scroll together. 
Is my Emacs 21.4.1 broken or my .emacs or is this just the way it works?

Answer (score 7):

You might be looking for follow-mode

It is minor mode that combines windows into one tall virtual window.

Answer (score 2):

If follow-mode doesn't work, you could define your own macro, something like

```
(defun align-windows ()
  (set-window-start (other-window) (window-start))
  (scroll-other-window))
```

Then either use this (along with scroll-down) instead of C-v, or rebind C-v to that, or add
advice to scroll-down.

Answer (score 1):

You can start Follow mode and setting up a basic two-window layout using

M-x follow-delete-other-windows-and-split RET.

it is from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FollowMode